# How do I get my position by use openstreetmap

Tags: android, openstreetmap

this is my code to get my position:

```
IMyLocationProvider ilp = new IMyLocationProvider() {
        @Override
        public void stopLocationProvider() {
        }
        @Override
        public boolean startLocationProvider(IMyLocationConsumer arg0) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public Location getLastKnownLocation() {
            return null;
        }
    };
MyLocationNewOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationNewOverlay(getApplicationContext(), ilp,mMapView);
mMapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation(ilp);
myLocationOverlay.enableFollowLocation();
```

but result is the screen turned blue and no map,where is the mistake?

[image]

Comment: You've implemented your own custom location provider that never returns a location, this is never going to work.

Comment: I use "GeoPoint myLocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        mController.setCenter(myLocation);" but it takes an error"NullPointException"

Comment: yes, because `getLastKnownLocation()` returns null

Comment: Then how to obtain the current position? is the class I use wrong?

Comment: You have to use Android's `LocationManager`, either directly or within your own class.